# Interseção entre listas sem elementos repetidos

Tags: python, lista

Tenho que fazer um código que leia duas strings de números, converta-as em `int`, armazene numa lista e imprima a lista A (números da primeira string), lista B (números da segunda) e lista C (números em comum nas duas listas). Já fiz o código porém quando vou imprimir a lista C ela repete os números em vez de mostrá-los apenas uma vez.
Exemplo:

```
lista A = [1 2 1 1 1]  
lista B = [1 3 4 5 6]
```

Mas na lista C, em vez de imprimir só `[1]`, ela imprime `[1, 1, 1, 1]`.

Obs: Eu sei que existem funções no Python que fazem a interseção, mas o intuito do exercicio é fazer sem usá-las.

```
A = []
B = []
C = []
C2 = []
A = input('A: ')
B = input('B: ')
A = A.split()
B = B.split()
for x in range(0, len(A), 1):
    A[x] = int(A[x])
for x in range(0, len(B), 1):
    B[x] = int(B[x])
for y in A:
    for x in B:
        if x == y:
            C = C + [x]
[C2.append(i) for i in C]
print("A =", A)
print("B =", B)
print("C =", C2)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Uma opção é, para cada elemento de `A`, verificar se ele existe em `B` e ainda não existe em `C`:

```
A = list(map(int, input('A: ').split()))
B = list(map(int, input('B: ').split()))
C = []
for x in A: # para cada elemento de A
    if x in B and x not in C: # se também está em B e ainda não está em C
        C.append(x)
```

Repare também que dá para simplificar a leitura das listas (fazer o `split` e transformar os valores em `int` de uma vez). E também não precisa da lista auxiliar `C2`.

---

Foi dito que não podem ser usadas as "funções do Python que fazem a intersecção", mas apenas para deixar registrada a solução com [`set`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#types-set):

```
C = list(set(A) & set(B))
```

Lembrando que um `set` não garante a ordem entre os elementos, então `C` não necessariamente terá os elementos na mesma ordem em que aparecem nas listas originais.

---

Vale lembrar que a solução com `set` é mais eficiente, já que a primeira opção tem que varrer as listas `B` e `C` várias vezes para verificar se o elemento existe. Fazendo um teste rápido com o [módulo `timeit`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/timeit.html):

```
from random import choices
# gerar listas aleatórias com 1000 números entre 0 e 99 (para ter elementos repetidos)
r = range(100)
A = choices(r, k=1000)
B = choices(r, k=1000)

from timeit import timeit
# executar cada teste 100 vezes
params = { 'number': 100, 'globals': globals() }
opcao1 = """C = []
for x in A:
    if x in B and x not in C:
        C.append(x)"""
opcao2 = "C = list(set(A) & set(B))"

# imprime o tempo em segundos
print(timeit(opcao1, **params))
print(timeit(opcao2, **params))
```

Os tempos podem variar de uma máquina para outra e depende de vários fatores (se havia outros processos rodando, se há muitos números repetidos nas listas, etc), mas em geral, na minha máquina obtive tempos por volta de 0,2 segundos com o `for` e 0,004 segundos com `set` (ou seja, a solução com `set` foi cerca de 50 vezes mais rápida).

Answer (score 1):

Outra forma interessante para resolver esta questão é a seguinte:

```
from itertools import chain

A = [int(x) for x in input('Valores de "A": ').split()]
B = [int(x) for x in input('Valores de "B": ').split()]
C = list()
for item in chain(A, B):
    if (item in A) and (item in B) and (item not in C):
        C.append(item)
C.sort()
print(C)
```

Observe que quando executamos este código recebemos primeira mensagem: `Valores de "A":` . Neste momento devemos digitar **todos** os elementos da lista `A`, na **mesma** linha, **separados** por um só espaço e pressionar `enter`. Em seguida, receberemos a segunda mensagem: `Valores de "B":` . Neste momento devemos digitar todos o elementos da lista `B` tal como digitamos na lista `A` e pressionar `enter`.

**Observação 1:**

Os objetos "A" e "B" são `listas`. Estas foram montadas a partir de `List Comprehension`.

**Observação 2:**

Ao utilizar o método `chain` da biblioteca `itertools`, habilitamos o código para trabalhar com listas de tamanhos diferentes.

Depois de termos digitados todos os valores de ambas as listas, o bloco `for`, com ajuda do método `chain` da biblioteca `itertools`, irá percorrer ambas as listas de forma simultânea. A cada iteração, será verificado se a variável temporária - `item` - está contida em ambas as listas - `A` e `B` - e se não está contida na lista `C`. Caso positivo, o valor de `item` será armazenado na lista `C`. Em seguida, a referida lista é ordenada de forma crescente e, posteriormente, exibida.

**Observação 3:**

Como já foi mencionado na outra resposta, todo este procedimento poderia ser realizado de forma mais eficiente se, por acaso, utilizarmos o `set`. A resolução com a função `set` seria:

```
A = [int(x) for x in input('Valores de "A": ').split()]
B = [int(x) for x in input('Valores de "B": ').split()]

print(sorted(list(set(A) & set(B))))
```