# Comparar os valores de duas lists

Tags: python, python-3.x

Então, eu acabei de começar a aprender Python e eu gostaria de saber como comparar os valores de duas lists, mais especificamente, saber os valores que coincidem nelas, exemplo

```
a = [30, 35, 40, 50]
b = [25, 35, 40, 55]

result = [35, 40]
```

Comment: Isto responde à sua pergunta? [Interseção entre listas sem elementos repetidos](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/477374/interse%c3%a7%c3%a3o-entre-listas-sem-elementos-repetidos)

Answer (score 0):

Você pode usar a classe `set()` que provê algumas funções como união, interseção, diferença e entre outras, no seu caso você que a interseção, então é só fazer `result = set(a) & set(b)` que irá retornar `{35, 40}` que é um objeto do tipo 'set', que para transformar em lista é só fazer a conversão `result = list(result)`, ou converter durante a operação `result = list(set(a) & set(b))`

Você pode ver mais sobre set em: https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/set.

Answer (score -1):

Bom, depende de como você quer comparar. Se você quer saber se os valores são iguais, faça isso:

```
a = [30, 35, 40, 50]
b = [25, 35, 40, 55]

for listA in a:
  for listB in b:
    if listA == listB:
      print("O valor %s e igual ao valor %s"%(listA, listB))
    else:
      print("O valor %s nao e igual ao valor %s"%(listA, listB))
```

Se você quiser comparar para ver se os valores são maiores ou menores, troque o "==" por ">"(maior), "<"(menor). ">="(maior ou igual), "<="(menor ou igual).